# uploading file on Rackspace for BlackBerry

Tags: java

I want to upload file on "rackspace cloud files". Is there any api available to do so? or any suggetions to implement this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All API docs for Rackspace can be found at http://docs.rackspace.com.

To upload a file for cloud files, you'll need to authenticate first and get a token:
http://docs.rackspace.com/auth/api/v2.0/auth-client-devguide/content/POST_authenticate_v2.0_tokens_.html

Then you'll need to use that token to create an object:
http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Create_Update_Object-d1e1965.html